# How to invoke Nashorns `ScriptFunction` callback from Java?

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, nashorn

I have some javascript code that is executed onto my object in Java Nashorn:

```
scriptEngine.eval("my.fn(function(a,b) {...}");
```

I can create method `fn` in my class that receives the `ScriptFunction`, but I don't get how to pass arguments and invoke this function from Java.

EDIT

I can make `fn(Runnable)` or `fn(Callable)` but I still don't know how to pass arguments to any of these two, from my Java implementation of `fn`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please avoid using any nashorn internal types like `jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction` in your Java code. With jdk9, jigsaw modular access checks prevent accessing such types from user code!

If you do want a callback to be passed to your Java code which is implemented in Nashorn script, there are two approaches:

1) Accept any `@FunctionalInterface` type in your code (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) like `Supplier`, `Consumer`, `Function` etc. Nashorn allows any script function to be passed as argument when a functional interface object is needed in java code. From script, you can pass a script function. On java side, you just invoke just as an interface method (like "get", "accept", "apply" etc. - these are functional methods on `Supplier`, `Consumer`, `Function` respectively)

2) Accept `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject` ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/JSObject.html) type argument in your Java code. From script, you can pass a script function as an argument when JSObject is needed in Java call. From Java code, you can invoke "call" method on JSObject [ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/JSObject.html#call-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...- ]

Comment: And what happens when your java code has an overload like `public Promise then (Consumer onFulfilled, Consumer onRejected)` and also `public Promise then (Function onFulfilled, Function onRejected)` ... `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Can't unambiguously select between fixed arity signatures` added an additional overload for then(JSObject... same error. Anyway to keep the overloads and have nashorn default to a fallback? Having a ScriptFunction overload doesn't resolve the error either FYI